# Rasterize list of 3d points into 2d canvas

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, projection

I have a List of 3D Points, this list looks something like (but contains around 45k points)

```py
ps = array([[0.77258706, 1.1149821 , 1.0494938 ],
       [0.77258706, 1.1149821 , 1.0494938 ],
       [0.77258706, 1.1149821 , 1.0494938 ],
       [1.3196146 , 1.2129393 , 0.96248001],
       [1.3197775 , 1.2117194 , 0.96213955],
       [1.3199375 , 1.2104989 , 0.96179962],
       [1.3200942 , 1.2092786 , 0.96145791],
       [1.3202487 , 1.2080572 , 0.96111906],
       [1.3204001 , 1.2068353 , 0.96078068]])
```

and I want to project these onto a 2D Canvas.

Due to the Pointcloud already being aligned correctly, I can just take the x and y coordinates directly from the points and use the z component to set the color (all the values get scaled to fit on the canvas).

```py
canv = np.zeros(shape=[3840, 2160, 3])
for p in ps:
    x_pos = p[0] * scale_factor
    y_pos = p[1] * scale_factor
    val =   p[2] * color_scale_factor
    canv[int(x_pos)][int(y_pos)][0:3] = colors[int(val)].get_rgb()
```

Currently this takes ca. 120ms per frame (8FPS).

Is there a way to significantly improve this by using some numpy magic?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, can you also show what the type of `colors` and `ps` is?

Comment: ps is an array as shown above (ps meaning points) and colors is a array of "color objects" and .get_rgbs makes it into rgb triples. I have already precalculated the rgb triples in an improved version making it a array of triples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use numpy functions instead of looping over the points:

```
x_pos = (p[:, 0] * scale_factor).astype(int)
y_pos = (p[:, 1] * scale_factor).astype(int)
val =   (p[:, 2] * color_scale_factor).astype(int)
```

Since `colors` seems like a list of some kind of `Color` object, you can pre-calculate an array of RGB values prior to doing anything:

```
colors_rgb = np.array([c.get_rgb() for c in colors])
```

Then, you can index into this array using your `val`:

```
canv[x_pos, y_pos] = colors_rgb[val]
```

---

To demonstrate this, I'm going to use an example list of points and a smaller canvas:

```
canv = np.zeros((4, 4, 3))
p = np.array([[0.1, 0.1, 0],
              [1.1, 1.1, 1],
              [2.2, 2.2, 2],
              [3.3, 3.3, 3]])

scale_factor = color_scale_factor = 1
```

Assuming `colors` contains a bunch of `Color` objects (it doesn't matter what it contain as long as `Color.get_rgb` gives a (at least) 3-long iterable):

```
class Color:
    def __init__(self, r, g, b):
        self.rgb = np.array([r, g, b]) / 255

    def get_rgb(self):
        return self.rgb

colors = [Color(255, 0, 0), Color(0, 255, 0), Color(0, 0, 255), Color(128, 128, 0), Color(0, 128, 128), Color(128, 0, 128)]
```

We have `colors_rgb` as:

```
array([[1.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 1.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 1.        ],
       [0.50196078, 0.50196078, 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.50196078, 0.50196078],
       [0.50196078, 0.        , 0.50196078]])
```

and `canv` becomes:

```
array([[[1.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
        [0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
        [0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
        [0.        , 0.        , 0.        ]],

       [[0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
        [0.        , 1.        , 0.        ],
        [0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
        [0.        , 0.        , 0.        ]],

       [[0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
        [0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
        [0.        , 0.        , 1.        ],
        [0.        , 0.        , 0.        ]],

       [[0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
        [0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
        [0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
        [0.50196078, 0.50196078, 0.        ]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

There is probably some improvements to be found using numpy vectorized functions instead of the for loop, however since I don't know what colors[val].get_rgb() does, I cant suggest a solution for that.

However you can try wrapping your function in a numba jit wrapper, this precompiles the python code and can execute the for loop in parallel.

```py
import numba as nb
@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def convert(array_3d):
    canv = np.zeros(shape=[3840, 2160, 3])
    for p in array_3d:
        x_pos = p[0] * scale_factor
        y_pos = p[1] * scale_factor
        val =   p[2] * color_scale_factor
        canv[int(x_pos)][int(y_pos)][0:3] = colors[int(val)].get_rgb()
    return canv
```